# If already aws s3 bucket exist how can I modify it

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, yaml, cloud, aws-cloudformation

I created yaml file which is creating s3 bucket in us-east-1 and attaching replication rule on it with existing bucket in us-west-2. My problem is I wanna use my same template yaml file with if I have already exist bucket in us-east-1 and for replication rule with us-west-2. There are has to solution with if s3 bucket already exist don't create and just modify it. But unfortunately I couldn't do it anyone check my code and help me?

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Parameters:
 BucketName:
    Type: String
    Default: test-source-us-east-1

Resources:
 s3bucket:
    Type: 'AWS::S3::Bucket'
    UpdateReplacePolicy: Retain
    Properties:
      BucketName: !Ref BucketName
      VersioningConfiguration:
        Status: Enabled
      PublicAccessBlockConfiguration:
        BlockPublicAcls: true
        BlockPublicPolicy: true
        IgnorePublicAcls: true
        RestrictPublicBuckets: true
      ReplicationConfiguration:
        Role: !GetAtt PublicBucketReplicationRole.Arn
        Rules:
          - Id: us-east-1
            Status: Enabled
            DeleteMarkerReplication:
              Status: Enabled
            Priority: 1
            Filter:
              Prefix: ''
            Destination:
              Bucket: 'arn:aws:s3:::test-source-us-west-2
 PublicBucketReplicationRole:
    Type: 'AWS::IAM::Role'
    DeletionPolicy: Retain
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service: s3.amazonaws.com
            Action: 'sts:AssumeRole'
      Policies:
        - PolicyName: S3ReplicationConfigurationAccessRole
          PolicyDocument:
            Statement:
              - Effect: Allow
                Action:
                 - 's3:ListBucket'
                 - 's3:GetReplicationConfiguration'
                 - 's3:GetObjectVersionForReplication'
                 - 's3:GetObjectVersionAcl'
                 - 's3:GetObjectVersionTagging'
                 - 's3:GetObjectRetention'
                 - 's3:GetObjectLegalHold'
                Resource:
                 - 'arn:aws:s3:::test-source-us-east-1'
                 - 'arn:aws:s3:::test-source-us-east-1/*'
                 - 'arn:aws:s3:::test-source-us-west-2'
                 - 'arn:aws:s3:::test-source-us-west-2/*'
              - Effect: Allow
                Action:
                 - 's3:ReplicateObject'
                 - 's3:ReplicateDelete'
                 - 's3:ReplicateTags'
                 - 's3:ObjectOwnerOverrideToBucketOwner'
                Resource:
                 - 'arn:aws:s3:::test-source-us-east-1'
                 - 'arn:aws:s3:::test-source-us-east-1/*'
                 - 'arn:aws:s3:::test-source-us-west-2'
                 - 'arn:aws:s3:::test-source-us-west-2/*'
 s3bucketPolicyALID0987:
    Type: AWS::S3::BucketPolicy
    Properties:
      Bucket:
        Ref: s3bucket
      PolicyDocument:
        Statement:
          - Action: s3:*
            Condition:
              Bool:
                aws:SecureTransport: "false"
            Effect: Deny
            Principal: "*"
            Resource:
              Fn::GetAtt:
                - s3bucket
                - Arn
        Version: "2012-10-17"
```

It will be reusable for creating new s3 or exist s3 bucket(*don't try create it*) again in us-east-1 to make synchronizing with in us-west-2 bucket.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to add `DeletionPolicy: Retain` to the template's resources and then import existing resources to a stack.

The process is like:

- Create the stack but do not specify the resources to be imported
- Wait for the stack to create
- Now add the resources to be imported to the template
- Finally use `Import resources into stack option` from the UI (or use `aws cloudformation create-change-set --resources-to-import` ... with the cli.

Reference: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/resource-import-existing-stack.html